# Use Swift Identifiable on Linux

Tags: swift, linux

I have some Swift Code that relies on the Identifiable Protocol and I want to use this code on Linux, but I noticed that Identifiable is only available for Apple Platforms. So is there any easy way to reimplement Identifiable for other Platforms?

I know that Identifiable is part of the swift standard library but its tagged with @available only for apple platforms. If you jump to the implementation you can see the following:

```swift
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6, *)
public protocol Identifiable {

    /// A type representing the stable identity of the entity associated with
    /// an instance.
    associatedtype ID : Hashable

    /// The stable identity of the entity associated with this instance.
    var id: Self.ID { get }
}
```

I saw there's an ongoing project to rebuild SwiftUI for other Platforms: https://github.com/Cosmo/OpenSwiftUI but they haven't done Identifiable yet. I am mentioning this because SwiftUI heavily relies on SwiftUI for Lists and ForEach
So anything you know that might help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [`Identifiable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable) is not SwiftUI-only but a part of `Swift Standard Library`.

Comment: But its marked @availabele only for apple platforms